# How to bend extrusion along a sphere

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

I have this extrusion I made out from the side of a curved mesh (not as in "Curve" or "Path", but just generally at a curve) and when I extrude it out, the it comes as a bar from the face I extruded from (like it should). How would I be able to make the extrusion curve at the angle my original mesh is at? 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's a way to automatically find the perfect curve but you could try this with <kbd>W</kbd> > *LoopTools* > *Bridge Edge Loops* then play with the factors on the bottom of the *Tools* panel in 2.7 (or bottom left *Adjust Last Operation* box in 2.8), especially *Segments* and *Strength*.

[image]

Comment: So this definitely works, but my curve looks like its almost leaning to one side of the bridge. Do you know how I could center it out a little?

Comment: could you please share this part of your mesh? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/